# before distributing : Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, undefined

Just before distributing my app throughout App Store, I'm getting this error.
I've did move some files from other project, but I did check on compile sources for the .m files ( they were already there so I didn't had to add any files). Plus, I've changed the " build architecture only " to No.
Another change I've did is leave only 'armv7' on " valid architectures ". 
The error is :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWFeedParser", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ListadoArticulosViewController.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
   clang: error:
```

Now the MWFeedparser class is from the cocopods installation located at other pod, so I didn't do any rough changes in the pod ( should I ? ) . 
Note : the project do work in my release and debug profile, I'm getting this error only with my distribution profile. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

for those who stuck with this annoying error, all you got to do is add the (mwfeedparser).a to the compile sources . I spent hours to figure it out hope it's going to be helpful to someone.